# How to execute an async task with socket.io and node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I receive an "on" event on the server side, I want to start a task in parallel so it does not block the current event loop thread. Is it possible to do so? How?

I don't want to block the server side loop and I want to be able to send back a message to the client once the task is done, something such as:

```
client.on('execute-parallel-task', function(msg) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do something that takes a while
        client.emit('finished-that-task');
    },0);
    // this block should return asap, not waiting for the previous call
});
```

I am not sure if setTimeout will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need the setTimeout.
Your function(msg) will be called once the execute parallel task finishes.

if you are designing a task to run in an async manner, you can look at something like the async lib for node.js

[Async Node JS Link](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: I can use async.parallel without problems but would the server be answering other requests while my (do something that takes a while) is running? will it run both codes at the same time?

Comment: yes, that's the way async works...It's basically one thread (you do not have threads in node.js)...whenever one part is waiting for something to happen other code runs and when something happens an event is called on the right handler handles it.. http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=127

Comment: if you need threading model, you might have picked the worng technology for your backend...having multiple processes communicate between them is not as efficent as threads..in fact you'd be creating threads using processes == much higher overhead with lots more complexity for no payout..

Comment: thanks dory! so if you have a request that you know that it will take a while to answer to (even if async answering it) you should pick another technology?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what the *takes a while* is. If it *takes a while* asynchronously (you can tell because you'll have to register a callback or `complete` handler), and *takes a while* because it's blocked on something like IO, rather than CPU bound, it'll inherently be *parallel*.

If however, its something synchronous or CPU bound, whilst you can use `setTimeout`, `setImmediate` etc. to  send back a message immediately, once the handler for `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` executes, your single thread of execution will be stuck handling that; you're not really *fixing* the problem, merely deferring it.

To exhibit true parallel behaviour, you'll need to launch a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You can use the message passing functionality to notify your worker what work to do, and to notify the parent process once the work is complete.

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork(__dirname + '/my-child-worker.js');

n.on('message', function(m) {
  if (m === "done") {
      // Whey!
  }
});

n.send(/* Job id, or something */);
```

Then in `my-child-worker.js`;

```
process.on('message', function (m) {
    switch (m) {
        case 'get-x':
            // blah
        break;
        // other jobs
    }

    process.send('done');
});
```

Comment: the child process seems perfect but I should run a bash process, and I just wanted to run a javascript function. the entire node.js running model is a single thread one so I can only run two threads if spawing a new process?

Comment: Each child process will have its own thread, separate to the parent process's thread. This gives you parallel execution. Does that answer your question... I didn't understand your comment fully!

Comment: so you're using node.js to create processes, using ipc to simulate threads in node.js? wouldn't it be better to use a thread supported server instead?

Comment: @DoryZidon: I never said that wouldn't be a better solution. The OP asked how to get parallel execution in a NodeJS environment. This is the answer.